# onchange this.form.submit() not working for web form

Tags: javascript, submit, form-submit, onchange

been working on this way too long...but can't seem to identify the problem. Already read dozens of articles on stackoverflow and elsewhere.

when I click and change the value, it doesn't auto-submit:

```
   <form id="orderbyfrm" name="orderbyfrm" action="http://staging.whiterabbitexpress.com/" method="post" class="orderbyfrm">
            <input name="s" value="<?php echo $wre_search_txt?>" type="hidden">
            <label for="orderby" class="sortByLabel">Sort by&nbsp;</label>
            <select class="sortByDropdown" name="orderby" id="orderby" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option value="Relevance">Relevance</option>
                <option value="likes" selected="selected">Likes</option>
            <option value="comments" selected="comments">Comments</option>
            </select>
</form>
```

in Chrome inspector I see an error 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null" onchange

I also tried onchange="javascript:document.orderbyfrm.submit" but that didn't work either.

Comment: might be a problem of scope. Check the scope of `this`

Comment: I also tried onchange="javascript:document.orderbyfrm.submit" but that didn't work either.

not sure how to change the scope of 'this'. if this scope is wrong, is any a workaround?

Comment: are you sure you pasted the exactly same form? this form has no issues ..

Comment: @Varun Achar, Problem cannot be in _scope of `this`_ because inside event code which defined in attribute `this` always point to element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have element or JS object called `form` or `submit` somewhere, conflicting with the real form.

Most safe way is using document.getElementById:

```
<select onchange="SubmitForm('orderbyfrm');">
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function SubmitForm(formId) {
    var oForm = document.getElementById(formId);
    if (oForm) {
        oForm.submit(); 
    }
    else {
        alert("DEBUG - could not find element " + formId);
    }
}
```

Further debugging with good old alert.. instead of the `alert("DEBUG ...` have this:

```
var sDebugInfo = "found " + document.forms.length + " forms: \n";
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
    var curForm = document.forms[i];
    sDebugInfo += "name: " + curForm.name + ", id: " + curForm.id;
    sDebugInfo += "\n";
}
alert(sDebugInfo);
```

Depending on what you get, debug should continue.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I added an id="orderbyfrm" to the form and added this code, but now get:

DEBUG: count not find element orderbyfrm

ugg

Comment: Something very fishy is going on. When you put `alert(document.forms.length);` what you get?

Comment: where shoudl I put that exactly? anywhere?
I added it after the form, but it just echo's on my HTML
alert(document.forms.length);

Comment: Add this to the function, instead the current DEBUG alert.

Comment: This page does have other forms, which are necessary. But shouldn't matter right? The javascript is suppose to target only this particular form...if it were actually working.

Comment: See my edit. Do you see name and id `orderbyfrm` in the list now?

Comment: For the record, I called my `submit` button `"submit"` and that was the problem. As you suggested, this was preventing the `this.form.submit()` from executing as expected. I renamed the submit button it and the javascript part worked. Leaving this comment since it may be useful to others later on with this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys! I found the problem. I had a broken div around this form

```
<div id="orderby" class="orderby
<form id="xxx" name="xxx" action="#" method="post" class="orderbyfrm">
```

fixed:

Really appreciate your help everyone!