# Do modern browsers support onchange="this.form.submit()" for file upload?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I would like to have an upload form that automatically submits as soon as the user has selected a file.
This question has been asked many times before. If I understood the other threads correctly, this should work:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="fileToUpload" onchange="form.submit()" type="file"/>
</form>

<?php 
  if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"])){
    echo "You successfully entered a file for the upload!";
    // move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/my_image.png");
  }
?>
```

When I select a file, I see the file name briefling flashing instead of the "no file chosen". But $_FILES is not set.

- Replacing `onchange="form.submit()"` with `onchange="alert('test');"` leads to the expected alert box after file selection. (idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904189/11826257)
- I also tried it with an extra JavaScript function as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275917/11826257. That didn't work neither.

Do modern browsers block `onchange="form.submit()"` for `type="file"`?
I tried it with Firefox 68 and Microsoft Edge 84.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow `$_FILES` to detect your uploaded file, you need `name` attribute in your input tag. So change

```
<input id="fileToUpload" onchange="form.submit()" type="file"/>
```

to

```
<input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" onchange="form.submit()" type="file"/>
```

Comment: Oh, I feel stupid for having overlooked such a simple error. Everything works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Form `id` values are not submitted by default.  Only `name` values are.  Try changing `id` to `name` in the input tag, e.g.:

`<input name="fileToUpload" onchange="form.submit()" type="file"/>`